# Wolfram Alpha Application Programming Interface Not Working

Tags: python, wolframalpha

code:-

```
import wolframalpha

wolframappid = wolframalpha.Client("XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX")
res = wolframappid.query('temperature in mumbai')
answer = next(res.results).text
print(answer)
```

result:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Harsh/Desktop/Harsh Python Projects/Test.py", line 5, in <module>
    answer = next(res.results).text
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\wolframalpha\__init__.py", line 166, in text
    return next(iter(self.subpod)).plaintext
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

any ideas how to solve this issue? i have also tried next(res.results).plaintext but another error pops up..

code:-

```
import wolframalpha

wolframappid = wolframalpha.Client("XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX")
res = wolframappid.query('temperature in mumbai')
answer = next(res.results).plaintext
print(answer)
```

result:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\wolframalpha\__init__.py", line 86, in __getattr__
    val = self[name] if name in self else self[attr_name]
KeyError: '@plaintext'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:/Users/Harsh/Desktop/Harsh Python Projects/Test.py", line 5, in <module>
        answer = next(res.results).plaintext
      File "C:\Users\Harsh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\wolframalpha\__init__.py", line 88, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(name)
    AttributeError: plaintext
```

thanks in advance...